# Exploiting a string-based overflow on x86-64 with NX (DEP) and ASLR enabled

Tags: linux, x86-64, buffer-overflow, aslr, dep

Consider the following vulnerable code/program:

```
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char buf[16];
    strcpy(buf, argv[1]);

    return 0;
}
```

On IA-32 (x86, 32-bit) running Linux with NX and ASLR enabled, I would exploit this using GOT-overwrite technique, which essentially includes the following steps:

1. Overflow buffer till RIP
2. Overwrite RIP with the address of `strcpy@plt`
3. Use a clean gadget from `.text`, e.g. `pop edi ; pop ebp ; ret`, as return address for `strcpy`
4. Write arguments for `strcpy`: `&bss`-address as destination and one byte of `/bin/sh` using `.text`
5. Repeat steps 2-4 until `/bin/sh` is completely written to `&bss`
6. Overwrite GOT-entry of `strcpy` with `system` (using offset, requires knowledge about the used version of Libc - let's ignore this here)
7. Write `strcpy@plt` on the stack, followed by some 4-byte chunk and finally address of `&bss` which points to `/bin/sh`
8. Profit

I want to exploit this on x86-64 with the same mitigation measures enabled. But this is more difficult as imagined. Basically for the following reasons:

1. **x86-64 register-based calling convention**: Function arguments are passed using registers, not the stack. Therefore some additional ROP-gadgets are required to transfer the arguments from the stack into the appropriate register. This is a minor problem, but is also affected by the following problem:
2. **64-bit return address**: The RIP in x86-64 points to `.text` which is not even 32-bit long. Therefore NULL-bytes must be written on the stack to chain function calls. Basically one can write as much NULL-bytes as desired using chained calls to `strcpy` and taking advantage of the NULL-terminating character `strcpy` *always* writes. But one may only call `strcpy` once by only overwriting the least significant bytes of the RIP.

   ```
   |0x00000000|        (most significant bytes)
   |0x00deadbe| <- RIP (least significant bytes)
   |0x41414141|
   |0x41414141| <- SFP
   |   ...    |
   ```

These are the major problems I got with exploiting the program on x86-64 with NX and ASLR enabled. Are there any techniques which solve these problems? Or does x86-64 really prevent a working, shell-opening exploit?

Comment: If RIP is supposed to stand for the return-address, you need new terminology for x86-64.  Just like EAX is extended to RAX, EIP (the current Instruction Pointer) is extended to RIP.  So in x86-64, RIP is a register name, and doesn't (by itself) make a good name for the return address that RET will read.

Answer (score 0):

x86-64 does not prevent these type of exploits. See this [tutorial](https://blog.techorganic.com/2015/10/09/a-rop-primer-solution-64-bit-style/).

Comment: As this question assumes x86-64 with both ASLR and NX enabled, your link does not provide a solution:

"I had to cheat on this one a bit by turning off ASLR. Due to the nature of addressing on 64-bit systems, null bytes become a really big problem. For this particular challenge, it’s easy to overwrite RIP, but I could only return to a single gadget due to the null bytes."